# Load capacitance of mems oscillator

Tags: oscillator, mems

I am using [88E1512-A0-NNP2I000](https://www.marvell.com/content/dam/marvell/en/public-collateral/transceivers/marvell-phys-transceivers-alaska-88e151x-datasheet.pdf) in my design. It requires 25MHz clock signal on its XTAL_IN pin.

I will be providing the required 25MHz clock using [ASTMLPE-18-25.000MHZ-ER-ET](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/3/ASTMLP-1847855.pdf).

In the datasheet of [88E1512-A0-NNP2I000](https://www.marvell.com/content/dam/marvell/en/public-collateral/transceivers/marvell-phys-transceivers-alaska-88e151x-datasheet.pdf), it is mentioned that "XTAL_IN Rise" and "XTAL_IN Fall" should be 3ns(typical value).
[image]

[ASTMLPE-18-25.000MHZ-ER-ET](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/3/ASTMLP-1847855.pdf) has different Rise and fall-time based up on the CLoad.

[image]

I have following questions.

1. Is this Cload means the capacitance load offered by the "XTAL_In" pin of    transceiver?
2. In the datasheet of transceiver(page number 134) it is mentioned that "Input capacitance" of all pins is "5pF". This value will be CLoad for [ASTMLPE-18-25.000MHZ-ER-ET](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/3/ASTMLP-1847855.pdf)?

Edit:-
In my previous question, I asked if can use part number as alternative in place of actual part number.

In this question, I am asking with respect to technical specifications of both

[image]

Comment: This looks like a clone of your previous question that was closed. Why did you posted again instead of editing and asking for reopen?

Comment: I have edited question. How should i ask for re-opening a question?

Comment: @MightyBeard007 There's a "Reopen" button at the bottom of the closed question.